# Operation of Inserting in middle of linked list is giving me a wrong output

Tags: c++, linked-list

where am I going wrong in this insertion of the linked list problem?

```
Node *insertInMiddle(Node *head, int x)
{
    Node *temp = new Node(x);
    int len = 0;
    if (head == NULL)
        return temp;

    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        len++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    Node *curr2 = head;
    int mid = ((len % 2) == 0) ? (len / 2) : (len + 1) / 2;
 
    // is the problem here?
    while (mid-- >= 1)
        curr2 = curr2->next;
    temp->next = curr2->next;
    curr2->next = temp;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Please add the expected output for a few examples. What is the expected output when the list has an odd number of values: what is the middle then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation of `mid` is such that when the list size is even, the insertion happens too far to the right.

You can actually simplify the initialisation of `mid` to this:

```
int mid = (len - 1) / 2;
```

Or:

```
int mid = len / 2;
```

The difference between these two will only be be noticed when the list size is odd, like 1->2->3. If you want to insert 50 in the middle, then the first formula will modify the list to 1->50->2->3, while the second one will produce 1->2->50->3. As there is no true middle place, you'll have to choose what best suits you.

Comment: i am getting correct answer for shorter cases but longer test cases are still a problem

Comment: can you write complete code for this problem, please?

Comment: Which longer case?

Comment: 5 \n
242 748 114 441 751 \n
909

Comment: Its Correct output is:

242 748 114 909 441 751

And My Code's output is:

242 748 114 441 909 751

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when you change your code like I wrote in my answer (one line changes), then the output will be either `242 748 114 909 441 751` (when you do `int mid = len / 2`) or  `242 748 909 114 441 751` (when you do `int mid = (len - 1) / 2;`). See it run [on repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68515575operation-of-in). If you have different results, please link to a runnable snippet, as that must mean that some code that you didn't share has errors.

Comment: Yeah i applied the changes and yeah my all test cases ran well.

Answer (score 0):

It should give you the wrong output because you are using post decrement of Middle element to `>=1` while you traversing to the middle of the list.

Just assume if you have a list of 4 elements let's say `1->2->3->4` when you are iterating to come middle you are using `while(mid-- >= 1)` that actually brings you to middle -1 element instead of the middle.

Therefore you are inserting node after `1` in the example.

you need to use:

```
while (mid-- > 1)
```

I didn't see any other issue with your code.

Comment: 1 3 2 4  
I got this output with the changes you suggested